# Error: "cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::signals2::scoped_connection'"?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals, noncopyable, boost-signals2

```
class Whatever
{
public:
    virtual ~Whatever();

protected:
    Whatever();
    virtual void SomeMethod();
    void OnEventOccurred(int x);

    std::vector<boost::signals2::scoped_connection> boostSignalConnections_;
}
```

// .cpp

```
Whatever::SomeMethod()
{
    ...
    boostSignalConnections_.push_back(
        anObject->AddEventOccurredObserver(
            std::bind(&Whatever::OnEventOccurred,
                      this, std::placeholders::_1)));
    ...
}
```

(Note `AddEventOccurredObserver` just delegates to `boost::signals2::connect()` and returns the `boost::signals2::connection`)

I'm getting the following error.  It's hard to interpret template errors but it seems like the error is being caused at the member declaration of `std::vector<boost::signals2::scoped_connection> boostSignalConnections_;`

```
...\vc\include\xmemory(202): error C2248:  
    'boost::signals2::scoped_connection::scoped_connection' :
    cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::signals2::scoped_connection'
...\boost_1_47\boost\signals2\connection.hpp(234) : see declaration of
'boost::signals2::scoped_connection::scoped_connection'
...\boost_1_47\boost\signals2\connection.hpp(210) :
    see declaration of 'boost::signals2::scoped_connection'
...\vc\include\xmemory(201) : while compiling class template member function
'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(boost::signals2::scoped_connection *,_Ty &&)'
with
[
    _Ty=boost::signals2::scoped_connection
]
```

I've searched and I think it might have to do with scoped_connection not being copyable?  I'm not sure.  The reason I'm using a scoped_connection is because of this SO question: 
[Handle connection/disconnection of many signals/slots with boost::signals2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265797/handle-connection-disconnection-of-many-signals-slots-with-boostsignals2)

**Update**

FYI, when I change from `scoped_connection` to `connection` it works: `std::vector<boost::signals2::connection> boostSignalConnections_;`.  My whole reason for using `scoped_connection` is that they automatically disconnect the connection on destruction whereas I believe a `connection` doesn't not.  However, I can just iterate over the collection and manually disconnect each one.

Comment: You're correct that the problem is that the copy constructor is private.  Since `vector` needs to copy the elements in the case of a reallocation (e.g. due to expansion), this is a problem.  I don't have the best solution for you though, so I'll leave it to other to actually answer the implicit question of "what should I do instead?"  My first, naive response would be to keep a vector of pointers/references to heap-allocated connections, but that obviously pretty much eliminates the usefulness of the `scoped` part of the equation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`boost::signals2::scoped_connection` is non-copyable, and in C++03, `std::vector<T>` requires that `T` be both copy-constructible and copy-assignable (this requirement is relaxed in C++11, where a non-copyable type is fine as long as it's movable instead).

The naive solution would be to make `boostSignalConnections_` a `std::vector<scoped_connection*>` instead, but this introduces object lifetime and exception-safety issues that aren't worth the effort. Instead, depending on how recent your compiler is, I'd recommend the following:

- C++03: Use [`boost::ptr_vector<scoped_connection>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/), which will store pointers for you (allowing non-copyable types) but give you value-semantics, and eliminate the aforementioned object lifetime and exception-safety issues.
- C++11: The above is still a valid option, but the more idiomatic approach would be to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<scoped_connection>>`.

That being said, why used `scoped_connection` if you don't want your object to be lexically-scoped?

Comment: Good question, but as I mentioned I was following the example in the question linked to in my question (although that uses a map so maybe it's different?) It seemed unusual to me to use a scoped object in container but I'm not that familiar with them.

Comment: @User : Right, associative container values have weaker requirements than sequence container values and associative container keys.

Comment: @ildjarn When you say `boost::ptr_vector<>` maintains object lifetime, does it mean it is deploying smart_pointers at the backend to achieve the same? If so, which one?

Comment: @CinCout : I haven't looked at the implementation but AFAIK that's a non-public implementation detail; likely it wouldn't be useful outside of the context of the library. Better to think of `boost::ptr_vector<>` as a "smart container" that obviates the need for a smart pointer. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn So it is guaranteed that the memory management is handled by the container? Or are there any (extra)ordinary exceptions to the same?

Comment: @CinCout : It's guaranteed – that's the entire reason for the library's existence, after all. TBH I'm not sure what your question is that isn't addressed on the front page of the library docs...