# Is there an easy way to disconnect all boost signals in a class?

Tags: boost, signals-slots

I have defined a bunch of boost::signal2 in a class and connected them to some slots on class construction. Is there an api call in boost that disconnects all the signals owned by a class, like disconnect_all()?

so that I don't need to disconnect each signal one by one.

Comment: do you have list of these? Otherwise, how would the compiler "know" which signals are "owned"? We don't have reflection. Although I'm pretty sure there are auto-disconnecting signals in RAII style...

Answer (score 0):

There is the [boost::signals2::signal::disconnect_all_slots()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/signal.html#idp221469488-bb) method. It looks like what you are looking for.

**Edit based on a comment clarification**

As far as I know the `boost::signals2` has no 'one-method-call' feature to disconnect all signals either of a class or of a whole program.
A possible solution is described in [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265797/handle-connection-disconnection-of-many-signals-slots-with-boostsignals2).

Comment: I am aware of disconnect_all_slots(). It disconnects all the slots on a particular signal, which isn't quite what I want.

I want something like disconnect_all_signals();